# Unable to execute SSO for the ASP.NET web application running on WS 2016 via IIS 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-10, windows-server-2016

We have a legacy ASP.NET application running on the WS 2016 via IIS 10. We did specify all possible settings for the authentication section the way it is instructed for the SSO

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, no matter what was done the Single Sign On is simply not working. The user always is prompted with the authentication popup. And the irony is, on another server we have identical settings, and the Single Sign On works just fine

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: Try deleting cookies and try again.  The cookie may be using older settings.

Comment: What kind of SSO? If you want Kerberos to work, escalate to your domain administrators as DC and AD settings are all key players.

Comment: Kerberos? I am not sure what kind of SSO it is, just don't want the credential prompt. As I said, in another server all works with the same settings. How do I check DC and AD settings?

Comment: @jdweng unfortunately clearing browser data didn't help